# keep getting error "No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use path_provider to save html files. Here is my function:

```
 Future<Null> createHtmlFile(String content) async {
    // Get the system temp directory.
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();



    var file = await File(
            '${directory.path}/html/webpage${DateTime.now().toString()}.html')
        .create(recursive: true)
      ..writeAsString(content);
    print(file.path);
  }
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
```

at first the path provider didn't appear in `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m` and `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java` so i fought withe it, removed it from `pubspec.yaml` and installed it again and after couple times doing restarts and flutter clean and run the package appears in the files above

but i still getting that error
i tired everything 
`flutter packages get`
`flutter update-packages --force-upgrade`
`flutter upgrade`
`Flutter clean`

Comment: Try closing your IDE (VS Code or Android Studio etc.) and re open it again.
For me this always does the trick when I add new packages and get this exception...

Comment: i tired even with uninstalling the package  then run clean then closing ide then install again its crazy

Comment: FYI I got this same error when running unit tests. It's because one can't read/write to a local database in unit tests

Answer (score -1):

the only way i got through that error is by move my code to a new project.
so if you getting this error and try all the routine stuff that you can find all over the internet as a solution like `Flutter clean`, and it not working,
just move to a new project

Answer (score -1):

delete path provider from pubspec yaml then get package then but the last vesion of path provider

**`path_provider: ^1.6.8`**

and good luck